# Arguments issues

Tags: java, arguments, minecraft

So, I'm trying to add arguments for this command for my Minecraft plugin, I'm pretty new to this...

For some reason whenever I use the command "/bonustime 2 (or whatever integer argument) in-game, it doesn't change anything. Why? How can I fix this?

Here's the part of my code that contains the issue:

```
public boolean onCommand(Command cmd, String label, int[] args, CommandSender sender, Player player) {
    if(player.hasPermission("itemgiver.set") || player.isOp()) {
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bonustime") && sender instanceof Player) {


        if(args.length == 1) {
         player = (Player) sender;
         time = args[0] * 1200;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Players will now recieve their bonus every" + args[0] + " mins.");
        }

    return true;
    }

}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: So, what the plugin essentially does is give players bonus items every set amount of time. I want to be able to set a changeable delay so that they aren't constantly receiving items.

Comment: Whenever I try to use the command in-game it just returns what I have set for commands: in the plugin.yml.

Comment: Take a look in [schedules](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bukkit/5436/scheduler-programming).

You should save the time in a class variable so it is fixed to create your schedule

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can't really see anything wrong with the code at the first look. Is it possible, that you may just have forgot to register the command in your main.class?
Also check if you have listed the command in your Plugin.yml.

```
author: The Developer
version: 1.0.0
main: com.TheDeveloper.main.main
commands:
   bonustime:
     description: add some time
     permission: itemgiver.set
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure, that your Command is registered in your main class, otherwise your command won't even be noticed by the Server.